# Application of name lookup to just declared name

Tags: c++, declaration

```
int a;//1

int main()
{
    int a;//2
}
```

As said in 3.4/1:

> The name lookup rules apply uniformly to all names (including
>   typedef-names (7.1.3), namespace-names (7.3), and class-names (9.1))

Thus, for `//2` declaration name lookup will be applied. What name will be found?

Comment: Read the entire paragraph and consider the difference between *use* and *declaration*.

Comment: @molbdnilo //1 and //2 are both declarations.

Comment: @st-antario Exactly. And the next sentence in the standard says "Name lookup associates the use of a name with a declaration [...] of that name. Which *use* of the name "a" would be associated with any of these declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What name will be found?

The only thing possibly looked at will be the *declarative region*, to check whether `a` is not redeclared invalidly. Obviously nothing will be found.

Moreover, there is no such thing as (unqualified) name lookup done while declaring names, rather when using them. The standard says nothing about unqualified name lookup for names being declared, rather for names used in specific contexts, such as a name as a postfix-expression for a function call. In particular, names being declared have to satisfy certain conditions, whether they are local, in class or in namespace scope; it is beyound this post to list them all up.

Comment: It is not true, because in that case the program is ill-formed.

Comment: No, it is perfectly true, because we are talking about **//2** (you asked that in the last line of your post). The declarative region of the second `a` does not contain another declaration with the same name. Perhaps you should first read the standard (specifically §3.3.1) before asking or writing about this. Maybe then your questions would also be answered. :)

Comment: It seems I'm beginning to understand. But why is `there is no such thing as (unqualified) name lookup done while declaring names`? Can you get a reference to standard?

Comment: There is no such thing as name lookup done while declaring names, because **the standard never said so**. I can't quote something from the standard that doesn't exist. I editet my post and elaborated a little bit further.